# React router pass props in state undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass an object as a prop to a component through state using `Link` tag. I passed the prop correctly and logged it in the component. It was printed correctly. But when I refresh the screen in that component, that passed prop is undefined.

I used these code to pass the prop.

```
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: '/url',
        state: {
          widget: value
        }
      }}>
      Link text
    </Link>
```

Then, after navigating to the component, I used following code.

```
console.log(this.props.location.state);
```

In the first navigation, log shows the passed prop correctly. Then, when I reload the screen inside that component, passed prop is undefined. As I figured, it only gives us the values when we navigate directly. If we reload the screen, we can't access that prop again. **My problem is, is there any other way to get this prop permanently which means that doesn't disappear when reloading the screen?** *(Further, I don't want to pass it as a url parameter).*

Comment: You are correct in understanding the behavior. You can pass data as plain text in the path in query parameters, so a serialized object *could* be in the URL (*would need to be deserialized on the other end*), but you say you don't want to do that. Alternatively you can persist the object somewhere, like app state via redux, or local/session storage (before or after the navigation push) and retrieve on the receiving route when it mounts. Question: why are you reloading the page?

Comment: Actually since it is a web page, I was wondering if a user reload the screen for some reason, it will be a problem if data doesn't appear because it is undefined now.

Comment: In that case, I think you *should* persist that data somewhere, route state is really transient.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

write a function for onClick like

```
goToThatLink = (value) => {
  const {history} = this.props
  history.replace('/url', widget)
}
```

and,
Call that function

```
onClick={() => this.goToThatLink(value)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I access that passed data in the other end?

Comment: const {location} = this.props;
console.log(location.state.split())

Comment: Actually, passed prop is still undefined.

Comment: How is this different than what OP is already doing (other than obvious `Link` versus button(?) with onClick handler)? They are already using route state, which is lost on page reload.

Comment: Yeah it didn't change anything